# Im trying to upload a image to firebase but the code does not seem to work

Tags: javascript, firebase

Im trying to upload a image to fire base, I know i cant upload the image as is so I did something that takes a the image and converts it but it wont convert to base64 string properly and i keep getting the error "fileReader is not a function"

here is the function:

```
function encode(){
        var file = document.getElementById("inputFileToLoad").files; //get the file
        if (file.length > 0)
        {
            var fileToLoad = file[0];

            var fileReader = new fileReader();

            fileReader.onload = function(loadFileEvent) {
                var srcData = loadFileEvent.target.result; // <--- data: base64

                //connect to firebase and set it
                var uploadEncodedImg = new Firebase("https://image-uploads.firebaseio.com/");
                uploadEncodedImg.set({
                  img: srcData,
                });
                console.log("uploaded to Firebase");

                //get the image on firebase and load it off the server
                uploadEncodedImg.child('img').on("value", function(snapshot) {
                  console.log(snapshot.val());
                  document.getElementById("Encoded").src = snapshot.val();
                });
            }
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code seems correct, just one thing, when you called a new instance of fileReader, then start of the word should be a capital..

```
var fileReader = new fileReader();
```

should be

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
```

that should fix the issue (Check the spelling and case of the new instance of the function)

Comment: I had a look and it seems to work correctly now. thank you